# Poor accuracy at mnist csv data in tensorflow

Tags: csv, tensorflow, mnist

I'm trying to mnist for beginners, using csv data.
I got the csv data from [here](https://pjreddie.com/projects/mnist-in-csv/) and made each label one-hot vector.
Each row has 794dims(colum1~10 as a label and 11~794 as pixels).
Here is the code I wrote that results in the awful accuracy.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
import argparse
import sys

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy      as np

FLAGS = None

def main(_):
  # Import data
  def csv_to_numpy_array(filepath, delimiter):
      return np.genfromtxt(filepath,delimiter=delimiter, dtype=None)

  def import_data():
      print("loading training data")
      traindata = csv_to_numpy_array("data/mnist_train_onehot.csv",delimiter=",")
      [trainY, trainX] = np.hsplit(traindata,[10]);
      print("loading test data")
      [testY, testX] = np.hsplit(testdata,[10]);
      return trainX, trainY, testX, testY

  x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test = import_data()

  numX = x_train.shape[1] #784
  numY = y_train.shape[1] #10

  # Prepare the placeholder 
  x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, numX]) #input box
  y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, numY]) #output box

  #define weight and biases
  w = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([numX,numY]))
  b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([numY]))

  #create the model
  def model(X, w, b):
      pyx = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(X, w) + b)
      return pyx

  y = model(x, w, b)

  #cost function 
  loss = -tf.reduce_sum(y_*tf.log(y))
  # the loss and acc
  cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_*tf.log(y),reduction_indices=[1]))
  train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cross_entropy)
  init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
  correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
  accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

  sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
  tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

  # Train
  for i in range(1000):
      ind = np.random.choice(100,100)
      x_train_batch = x_train[ind]
      y_train_batch = y_train[ind]
        #run optimization op (backprop) and cost op (to get loss value)
      _,c = sess.run([train_step, loss], feed_dict={x: x_train_batch, y_: y_train_batch})
      if i % 50 == 0:
          train_acc = accuracy.eval({x: x_train_batch, y_: y_train_batch})
          print('step: %d, acc: %6.3f' % (i, train_acc) )

  # Test trained model
  print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: x_test,
                                      y_: y_test}))

if __name__ == '__main__':
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument('--data_dir', type=str, default='/tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data',
                      help='Directory for storing input data')
  FLAGS, unparsed = parser.parse_known_args()
  tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
```

The accuracy is 0.098pt.
Could someone please try this code and tell me what is wrong on this code?
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Try replacing `w = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([numX,numY]))` with `tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([numX, numY]))`. You should try to initalise your weights randomly. If they're all zeros the gradient descent might get stuck in the initial position. This might also be useful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eBbEDRsCmv4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is you code with the needed changes.  Specifically, you can use **tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits** to do the heavy lifting of calculating cross entropy for you.  Another improvement is to use **loss = tf.reduce_mean...** instead of **loss = tf.reduce_sum...***.  This will make your training correction be the average of all the errors that were made instead of the sum.  You'll get wild and uncontrolled training swings if you use sum and you'll have to compensate by using a really small gradient descent factor.  If you find you have to use something in gradient descent higher than 1 or lower than .1 you could probably fix the problem by using reduce_mean for the loss.

Here is your code.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
import argparse
import sys

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy      as np

FLAGS = None

def main(_):
  # Import data
  def csv_to_numpy_array(filepath, delimiter):
      return np.genfromtxt(filepath,delimiter=delimiter, dtype=None)

  def import_data():
      print("loading training data")
      traindata = csv_to_numpy_array("data/mnist_train_onehot.csv",delimiter=",")
      [trainY, trainX] = np.hsplit(traindata,[10]);
      print("loading test data")
      [testY, testX] = np.hsplit(testdata,[10]);
      return trainX, trainY, testX, testY

  x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test = import_data()

  numX = x_train.shape[1] #784
  numY = y_train.shape[1] #10

  # Prepare the placeholder 
  x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, numX]) #input box
  y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, numY]) #output box

  #define weight and biases
  w = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([numX,numY]))
  b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([numY]))

  y = tf.matmul(x, w) + b

  # unused for this model
  keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

  loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=y, labels=y_))
  train = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(loss)

  # Test trained model
  correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
  percent_correct = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

  init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

  sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
  tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

  # Train
  for i in range(1000):
      ind = np.random.choice(x_train.shape[0],100)
      x_train_batch = x_train[ind]
      y_train_batch = y_train[ind]
        #run optimization op (backprop) and cost op (to get loss value)
      _,c = sess.run([train_step, loss], feed_dict={x: x_train_batch, y_: y_train_batch})
      if i % 50 == 0:
          train_acc = percent_correct.eval({x: x_train_batch, y_: y_train_batch})
          print('step: %d, acc: %6.3f' % (i, train_acc) )

  # Test trained model
  print(sess.run(percent_correct, feed_dict={x: x_test,
                                      y_: y_test}))

if __name__ == '__main__':
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument('--data_dir', type=str, default='/tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data',
                      help='Directory for storing input data')
  FLAGS, unparsed = parser.parse_known_args()
  tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
```

Here is a link to a few different mnist tensorflow architectures https://github.com/panchishin/learn-to-tensorflow/blob/master/examples/mnist_model_comparison.py all in one script

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. 
I changed the loss function as you mentioned, as well as changing the initialization of Weight and Bias. 
But the accuracy is still low (0.53). I will refer to the link as well.

Comment: Looking at line 
"ind = np.random.choice(100,100)"
I can see you are only using the first 100 elements for training but you want to use all the training elements for training.  Try using
"ind = np.random.choice(x_train.shape[0],100)"

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I got the "plausible" result(0.89pt) thanks to your help. I understand that the usage of random choice in this case is "random.choice(#alldata, #batchsize)".
I'm so glad that you helped me. Thank you again.

Comment: Hey Ted, you are using only 1 fully connected layer, so a result of .89 is actually good.  If you add one or two 3x3 convolution layer you'll see a huge improvement.  Follow this link for a few mnist architectures and a comparison of their performance.   https://github.com/panchishin/learn-to-tensorflow/blob/master/examples/mnist_model_comparison.py  Your fully connected layer is forcing the NN to learn each pixils coorelation to the answer.  By adding one 3x3 convolution layer you will instead calculate correlation of features (such as curves and shades) to the end result.

Comment: @Ted if this improved your code, then please mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: where have you defined `accuracy` which you use to calculate model accuracy at `accuracy.eval()`? is that supposed to be `percent_correct.eval()`?

Answer (score 0):

There are possible problems:

1- Initialize your variables randomly and not zero

2- You may misunderstand the .csv file format, where you got .csv file, said the format is `label, pix-11, pix-12, pix-13, ...`

3- Try to use `tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits( logits , llabels ))` the method you use to compute loss is numerically unstable. **Update:** in this case dont use `tf.nn.softmax` because `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` internally have softmax normalizer and cross entropy.(thanks for @ml4294 comment)

Comment: Note: If you use `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()`, you should not use the `softmax()` function in your `model()` function, since the TensorFlow built-in softmax cross entropy function expects unnormalized logits.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I tried 1 and 3, then accuracy got a little bit higher (but still low, 0.53pt).
As for the format, I made the labels 10dims one-hot vector.
(ex. label 2 corresponds to [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]) Then it should not be wrong I guess...

Comment: Your welcome, the other suggestion can be, increase your batch size, and also try to shuffle your data, (not batch, but whole data at first) may be data are by order in .csv file.